# Consumer side behavior on using coGroupByKey in Apache beam

Tags: apache-beam

I have a beam job that reads data from 2 kafka producers and does a join using a common key in both streams. I am not using the partition key used by kafka to do the join. So essentially kafka partitions data by some key in both streams, my consumer/beam job consumes this data from the two streams and extracts the actual key using which I wish to perform join into a pCollection and then I run coGroupByKey.

I see the join happen for several events, but if I query for specific events, I do not see the join happen. I have used the same window to window into the two streams. This makes me question if a consumer is getting the right data from two streams to perform this join. Let's say that consumer 0 consumes from partition 0 of both streams. Is there a chance that kafka partitions data using a key x and my consumer 0 is not getting the right data to join across the streams. I was told that coGroupByKey ensures that the right data lands in each consumer, but I am not able to visualize this. How can using coGroupByKey affect the input side behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoGroupByKey will join data across all input partitions. I suspect the issue is windowing--are the unjoined items in the same window? (CoGroupByKey does not join across windows, so items that land in separate windows do not get joined. You could look at using session windows if fixed windows don't work.)

Comment: I tried with both session and fixed windows approach. My containers may be behind high watermark and I see a delay in the output after join.                                     `Window<T>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardHours(24)))
        .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
        .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
        .withOnTimeBehavior(Window.OnTimeBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY)
        .accumulatingFiredPanes();`